# pip3 cannot find Python.h when installing numpy on OS X

Tags: python, macos, numpy

My operating system is OSX 10.10.4 and I have both python2.7.10 and python3.5 and tried to install numpy, scipy and matplotlib for both this two versions of python.

In python2 it went well but as for python3, I tried to install numpy with command

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Then it turned out that the installation terminated because of it cannot find file Python.h But in fact the file python.h does exist in python3.5's directory. So I am quite confused now.

Update 18 Sept, the exact error messages:
initially it tried to build numpy:

```
  compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -c'
  clang: _configtest.c
  _configtest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
  #include <Python.h>
         ^
  1 error generated.
  _configtest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
  #include <Python.h>
       ^
  1 error generated.
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  Running from numpy source directory.
  /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
  .....
File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 293, in check_types
  "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
```

and then the installation reported the same error.

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue. Did you install Python3 using Homebrew? Is your Homebrew in a nonstandard path?

Comment: finally I followed miniconda and everything runs well now

Comment: can you post your solution as an answer. @BernardYuan

Comment: sure, I followed a tutorial in Chinese telling you how to set up the scientific computing environment on OS X, I would brief write the main idea and post it after my finals :) @sirvon

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/43916) this is fixed in version 1.9.3 of numpy. Try

```
pip3 install numpy==1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Python headers for OSX are kind of messed up/not installed by default nowadays. You can just run:

`xcode-select --install` and then install Command Line Tools and it should work.

Comment: what I don't understand is that in python2.7.10 it works well and in the directory of python3.5 I do have Python.h  Isn't it something wrong with the include directory?

Comment: Could be. Did my solution not work? It has to compile C libraries and where it looks and how the Makefiles work gets messy.

Comment: Replace the `#include <Python.h>` with `#include <Python/Python.h>` and see if that works. Or try to do pip3 install -U pip3 and then try, it looks like it might be getting the wrong version of Numpy.

Comment: I guess xcode-select installs OSX default python (which is 2.x). However, I have installed Python3.5 using Homebrew where I get the same error. I have absolutely no idea why I should modify c/c++ code from someone else, especially when its seems to be auto-generated by numpy.